# FT232h ACBUS 8/9 not working as TX&RXLED# in MPSSE mode

Tags: led, usb, ftdi

I use an FT232H in MPSSE mode and tried to use ACBUS8 and/or ACBUS9 as TX&RXLED# output.
I populated the EEPROM and programmed pins ACBUS8 and ACBUS9 as TX&RXLED# output.

As long as I use the chip in serial mode, ACBUS8 and ACBUS9 works as TX&RXLED# outputs as described in data sheet.

Unfortunately when software switches FT232H to MPSSE mode, ACBUS8 and/or ACBUS9 will **not** work any longer as TX&RXLED# output.

Any ideas how to use ACBUS8 and/or ACBUS9 in MPSSE mode as TX&RXLED# outputs?

Btw. in MPSSE mode the ACBUS8 and ACBUS9 pins can't be used as GPIO.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible unless you emulate it in software.  In MPSSE mode, those pins are no longer TXLED/RXLED; they become GPIO pins.